# Auto refresh/reload dlls between two solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have 2 visual studio solutions. So I am working with 2 visual studio instances.

One project in the first solution is referencing to another project in the second solution.

When the dll is changed on the disc is not refreshed in my solution. I dont get all the metadata.

Is there anyway to auto load changed dlls?

Thanks

Comment: add these two projects to one solution, and add a dependency between one project and the other

Comment: or just add the project as a project reference

Answer (score 1):

As Commented by @mcNets,

> You can add two projects in a single solution & then assign
>   dependencies in the projects.

**To assign dependencies to projects**

1. In Solution Explorer, select a project.
2. On the Project menu, choose Project Dependencies.The Project Dependencies dialog box opens.
3. On the Dependencies tab, select a project from the Project drop-down menu.
4. In the Depends on field, select the check box of any other project that must build before this project does.

Your solution must consist of more than one project before you can create project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your solution Choose **Batch Build**.
2. It will open the dialog where you can see all the projects in the solution.
3. Now check all the checkboxes in the build column for your project and also for the referenced project. both release and debug config.
4. Now click on build.
5. Once build is complete run your project.

Your problem will be resolved.